# How to get config field value for all available store views as an array?

Tags: magento2, configuration, scopeinterface

I have one configuration field with scope as `store view` in my module.

System config path: `vendor/module/title`

I have multiple websites with multiple store views and I want to get values of my field for each store view as an array.
I can use looping for website and store views to get value for my field for each store view with below code.

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('vendor/module/title', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $scopeCode);
```

and then store it in an array with `store_code` or `store_id` as the key.

Is there any other way I can achieve this? May be without loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may inject the given file path **\Magento\Store\Model\StoresConfig** in your dependencies and use the function **getStoresConfigByPath($path)**.

This function will return all the store values for a given path.

I hope this function meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your constructor

```
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository $storeRepo

$stores = $this->storeRepo->getList();
$storeList = array();
foreach ($stores as $store) {
  $storeId = $store["store_id"];
  $storeName = $store["name"];
  $storeList[$storeId] = $storeName;
}
return $storeList;
```

Comment: Thanks Vishnunath for the answer but I am looking to get values of my config field, not list of available stores.